# Product media gallery API

Tags: magento, gallery, media

I am working on a product page and need to create two separate galleries - one main gallery and additional one. Currently I output images with empty label on main gallery and images with specific prefix on additional one.

Is there a way to query only images labeled by specified label? I found only `getMediaGalleryImages` method which doesn't do anything specific.
Or maybe there is just the other way to work with the gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default there is no way to query images based on a labels or other conditions except for the main and thumbnail options. We use the following setup:

- Get a list of all images for the product
- Itinerate through each finding out all the details and sorting inside two arrays.
- Going through each array for each gallery and outputting the images inside the right tags.

Aother way of doing this would be to extend the product model and adding another gallery field. But that's IMO much too complex for something this simple.

Comment: Thanks, I did the same, iterated through gallery's images and added them to different arrays based on conditions. There is an overhead because I'm quering gallery in 3 templates: view.phtml, media.phtml and configurable.phtml but for now it's okay

Comment: You could extend the controller to sort these out for you and basically just do it once per page view, then just get the ready made arrays from the views. We also wanted to do something like this however use of caching made the benefits from "properly" doing it not worth it at the moment. Basically our double iteration only happens once each time new stuff gets added to the product.